# How do I specify the Spark configuration when running on EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-step-config

So I'm trying to run a Spark pipeline on EMR, and I'm creating a step like so:

```
// Build the Spark job submission request
val runSparkJob = new StepConfig()
  .withName("Run Pipeline")
  .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.TERMINATE_CLUSTER)
  .withHadoopJarStep(
    new HadoopJarStepConfig()
      .withJar(jarS3Path)
      .withMainClass("com.example.SparkApp")
  )
```

Problem is, when I run this, I encounter an exception like so:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

The thing is, I'm trying to figure out where to specify the master URL, and I can't seem to find it. Do I specify it when setting up the pipeline run step or do I need to somehow get the master `IP:port` into the application and specify it in the main function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify it in your application when create instance of SparkSession

Example for local run (Scala code)

```
val sparkSessionBuilder = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName(getClass.getSimpleName)
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
```

And you can find more information in [jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-SparkSession.html)
or in [spark.apache.org](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession)

When you launch a cluster you should specify step with command-runner.jar and pass to args you jar

```
val runSparkJob = new StepConfig()
  .withName("Run Pipeline")
  .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.TERMINATE_CLUSTER)
  .withHadoopJarStep(
    new HadoopJarStepConfig()
      .withJar("command-runner.jar")
      .withArgs("spark-submit",
           "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
           "--driver-memory", "10G",
           "--class", <your_class_to_run>,
           "s3://path_to_your_jar")
```

[To submit work to Spark using the SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html)

Comment: Ha! This is the solution: I was thinking the `withJar` was meant to specify the actual spark jar.

Answer (score 0):

With in your spark application you can do below... is option1

```
val sparkSessionBuilder = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName(getClass.getSimpleName)
      .master("yarn")
```

if you want to add it to stepconfig.... is option 2

```
// Define Spark Application
        HadoopJarStepConfig sparkConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
            .withJar("command-runner.jar")
            .withArgs("spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn"),
                    "--class","com.amazonaws.samples.TestQuery",
                    "s3://20180205-kh-emr-01/jar/emrtest.jar", "10", "Step Test"); // optional list of arguments

StepConfig customStep = new StepConfig()
                 .withHadoopJarStep(sparkConfig)  
                 .withName("SparkSQL") ;
```

I prefer option 2 since its not hard coded in the code.